# Using a job identifier to group ansible tasks into logical task group

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm new to ansible but trying to progress and learn.

I'm running a number of API calls to configure a web proxy tool.

The flow is essentially, make a GET request to see if the object exists,  if does not exist, follow up with a POST request to create the object. Pretty standard.

This procedure repeats itself multiple times as the product can have a number of instances of the same type of configuration.  So I would like to make the GET/POST routine as generic repeatable as possible, by associating an id.

The playbook is:

```
    set_fact:
      'vh_task_id': 01

  - name: check virtual host exists
    uri:
      method: GET
      url: "{{ admin_api_url }}/hosts?vHost={{ public_virtual_host|urlencode() }}"
      return_content: yes
      headers:
        X-XSRF-Header: "Access"
      user: "{{ admin_user }}"
      password: "{{ admin_password }}"
      status_code: 200
      validate_certs: no
    register: response

  - name: set fact virtual host task id response '{{ public_virtual_host }}'
    set_fact:
      'response_{{ vh_task_id }}': "{{ response }}"
```

This all works fine, up to this point and `response_{{ vh_task_id }}` correctly contains the response body from the above set_fact, as I can see it, if I output it.

The issue now becomes when I want to query the JSON in `response_{{ vh_task_id }}` as the variable to query to get the id value.

The set_fact, is setting a literal value of`response_01` rather than seeing the concatenation as a registered variable.

Here is an example of how I was trying to do it:

```
set_fact:
'vh_id': "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].response_{{ vh_task_id }} | json_query('json.items[0].id') }}"
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks for your time to come back, I tested this but, in the end, I have since learnt that using the with_items, gives me better results and it more repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```yaml
set_fact:
  'vh_id': "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].hostvar | json_query('json.items[0].id') }}"
vars:
  hostvar: response_{{ vh_task_id }}
```

Also you don't need explicit quote `'` for plain string as variable name. Like, you can change `'vh_id':` to `vh_id:` if no other reason to keep the name with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time to come back, I tested this but, in the end, I have since learnt that using the with_items, gives me better results and it more repeatable